# Java io.appium clashes with io.grpc

Tags: java, grpc-java, appium-java

I'm create some java 11 program (use maven) which using Appium for android testing and gRPC to communicate with other device.

Appium Dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
   <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
   <version>8.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

gRPC Dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
  <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
  <version>1.53.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
  <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
  <version>1.53.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
  <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
  <version>1.53.0</version>
</dependency>
```

When I run the program, I got error

```
Warning: [org.testng.ITest] implementation on class [com.framework.DynamicTest] returned null. Defaulting to method name
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.toImmutableMap(Ljava/util/function/Function;Ljava/util/function/Function;)Ljava/util/stream/Collector;
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumNewSessionCommandPayload.makeW3CSafe(AppiumNewSessionCommandPayload.java:40)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumNewSessionCommandPayload.<init>(AppiumNewSessionCommandPayload.java:54)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:229)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:80)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:92)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:117)
```

The error occurs when I hit this line

```
mobileDriver = new AndroidDriver(new URL(strURL), capabilities);
```

It's look like the AndroidDriver not detected. But when I remove gRPC dependency, it's work.

Is there a possible solution to using io.appium together with io.grpc?

Comment: Couple of things:

 - can you use the latest gRPC version (1.56.1)? 
 - if it still fails with the grpc latest version, try using the maven enforcer plugin https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireUpperBoundDeps.html to make sure the build is using the latest required version for Guava. And if the enforced flags an error explicitly depend on that guava version. Hope that works

Comment: Thankyou I already try it but it's still generate same error

Answer (score 1):

After add guava dependency (not the latest version), the error is resolved.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
   <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
   <version>31.1-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

Thankyou to @San P for giving advice.